# How to call play-framework script in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, playframework

I've exported play framework 1.2.1 in my user folder, inside "play-framework" and I'm now trying to run the script but I can't get it to.

When I'm inside the directory and simply type "play", it doesn't work, and I also tried renaming it to play.py and calling it with "python play.py", still nothing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the framework written in Java? Open up that `play` file and find out what language it's in.

Comment: the script is written in python

Comment: What happens when you run `python ./play`? Errors? Anything?

Comment: Yea it's working with `./play`. I didn't know the ./ was necessary..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
./play
```

from it's directory

Or add the directory to your PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/play-framework
```

And.. are you sure you get nothing as a response? Should be some error, like 'command not found'.

Comment: ./ not necessary because you've just added that directory to your PATH
http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html

Comment: For some reason I have to execute this command if i restart my computer. Any idea how to make it permanent?

Comment: Yes, sure. Add it into your profile, i.e. append that command in a new line at the end of ~/.basrc

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/play-framework
```

The path must be relative, check with 
`echo $PATH` 
in the command prompt